# Send checkbox selected value to controller on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to create checkbox each row level. Requirement is if user select any of the checkbox and click on button the entire row information i have to pass it to controller for further execution. Please help me how to achieve this.

This is Razor solution.

Cancel

```
@foreach (var saleOrder in Model)
                    {
                        <tr data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top">
                            <td><input type="checkbox" id="select" name="select" /></td>
                            <td class="text-center">@saleOrder.SalesId</td>
                            <td class="text-center">@saleOrder.TotalAmountPaid.ToString("0.00 €")</td>
                            <td class="text-center">@saleOrder.TotalAmount.ToString("0.00 €")</td>
                            <td class="text-center">@saleOrder.ExpectedDiscountAmount.ToString("0.00 €")</td>
                            <td class="text-center">@saleOrder.TransactionId</td>
                            <td class="text-center">@saleOrder.OperatorId</td>
                            <td class="text-center">@saleOrder.CashierId</td>
                            <td class="text-center">@saleOrder.ReceiptDate.ToString("ddMMyyyy")</td>
                            <td class="text-center">@saleOrder.CarAnomalyMessage</td>
                            <td class="text-center">@saleOrder.CarAnomalyType</td>
                        </tr>
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimum, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Stackoverflow is not a free code writing service.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `<input type="checkbox" id="select" name="select" />` use HTML Helper class.

`@Html.CheckBox("select", true)` which results as  `<input checked="checked" id="select" name="select" type="checkbox" value="true" />`

or use @Html.CheckBoxFor to loop

@model Model

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.selected)
```

Html Result:

```
<input data-val="true" 
        data-val-required="The isNewlyEnrolled field is required." 
        id="selected" 
        name="selected" 
        type="checkbox" 
        value="true" />
```